# Windows 8.1 no apps are installed to open this type of link (steam)

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe, steam, windows-store

Trying to install the game `PES 2020` in my laptop. After clicking PES2020.exe which is the installation file (or maybe the game run file itself), I get the message
I tried everything on the internet.

- Reset `Windows Store`,
- tried `Safe mode`,
- checked `regedit` .exe regarding values,
- tried opening the exe file from cmd.

But nothing works.

Does anyone have a clue?

[image: Error's Screenshot]

Comment: Are you 100% positive that PES 2020 actually came from the (Windows 8.1) Windows Store?  Have you tried to simply reinstall the game and Steam, because I can tell you, that particular game is NOT from the Microsoft Store at least on Windows 8.1.  Providing a screenshot of the exact error message would be helpful

Comment: I don't know. I just know it is from steam. But the error message comes from windows store! So strange. I have now included the screenshot in the post.

Comment: You are able to run other executables?  Have you tried to reinstall Steam and PES 2020?  Since the application is not actually from the Windows Store, any steps to dealing with the Windows Store, won't resolve your problem.

Comment: Also, I know that this game worked in my previous windows 8.1. I reinstalled windows 8.1 6 months ago. Maybe there is something with windows new updates?

Comment: Yes other .exe files work!

Comment: I haven't tried reinstalling Steam. I will take a chance on that.

Comment: Your problem is unique to your system and has nothing to do with any Windows updates that might have been installed. The error suggests you are unable to launch Steam is that the case?

Comment: I reinstalled Steam and now the error doesn't show up. But nothing happens after clicking PES2020.exe. Simply it does not open. At least I now know the problem was Steam!

Comment: Your system stratifies the requirements for this application?  It doing nothing sounds like you don’t have the prerequisites installed

Comment: Does launching the game from the Steam client work? Also, check the application events in your event log.